# Why does the ruby process continue to exist after the foreman finishes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, foreman

I'm running two Rails applications (one of which depends on the other (API)) on a local development machine for development.

Applications are relatively fat, with webpack and so on. Therefore, I closed my eyes to the fact that the Macbook Pro turns on the cooling at a sufficiently strong level.

The problem is that the cooling continued to work after I exited the foreman (responsible for starting and running applications). Recently I noticed that this is due to two ruby processes (from two applications), which do not stop working after the foreman finishes. They continue to exist further, and monitoring shows that they load the processor for a couple at 100%.

I'm currently solving the problem like this:

1. Foreman -> `Control + C`
2. `spring stop` for ruby process

Can you please tell me how can I solve this problem without a `spring stop` crutch?

**UPD**

Using [overmind](https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind) there is no such problem. When overmind exits, the ruby process also exits. But using overmind can't run two projects at the same time. So this utility isn't a solution.

Comment: Spring it is a separate proccess, it is a code preloader and works independently of Foreman so you will not able to stop Spring on Foreman termination. You can disable Spring completely by providing DISABLE_SPRING=1 variable but I think it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexTatarnikov I would like to understand why this problem with the ruby process occurs, why it is affected by the end of spring and how to fix it all.

Comment: @AlexTatarnikov But what I wrote about spring really helps. Maybe not directly, but through some kind of dependent manipulation, but it helps.

Comment: Foreman stops process which he runs but Rails spawn separate Spring process about which Foreman don't know and as result it can't stop it. Since Foreman dosen't has any hooks on stop where you can put "spring stop" you need to run it by yourself.

Comment: @AlexTatarnikov Let's try to approach from the other side. Why is the ruby process saved after the foreman finishes?

Comment: Spring it is an independent process, it doesn't rely on your rails server or any other ruby process is spinning or not. When you start e.g. your Rails server, Rails server starts Spring process. When you stop Foreman it stops your Rails server but Spring will still exist because Foreman not monitoring that process and has no control over it.

Comment: @AlexTatarnikov I think thats really as close to an answer as this question can get.

Comment: UPD: Rails server doesn't start Spring process, checked this right now(most likely you have Rails server in Foreman). But when you run rails console, rake, test, etc a separate Spring process appear. So it is something that really not related to Foreman at all.